# How can I delete Google Translate "Original text"

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with a wordpress plugin that uses Google Translate to translate pages. It appears a `h1` tag with the text "Original text" and I don't know how can I remove it.

I would like to remove the `h1` tag, so I am not interested in `CSS` changes.
Thanks in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Puts this javascript code in the footer.php, that remove the text in h1 "Original text"

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'es' }, 'google_translate_element');
    var removePopup = document.getElementById('goog-gt-tt');
    removePopup.parentNode.removeChild(removePopup);
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. What's "utilise ce"? French for "Use this"? Also, this is basically a code-only answer. A little explanation would improve the answer. Thank you!